# How to determine how many days left before a unix timestamp date?

Tags: php, date, unix, time

I need to get the days left before the date is reached, and if the timestamp is before the current date like 1990 or something, then it will display a message.

so say it's the 1st november of 2014
if the timestamp is before the first of november, 1st 2014, then it will display expired, else it will tell you how many days left before the date is reached.

thanks you very much.
**This is in php by the way.**

Comment: what have you come up with so far? how is the time being passed in? We can't give you a relevant answer without seeing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$current = time();
$target = '2014-11-01 00:00:00';
$target = strtotime($target);

if($target > $current){

     $span = $target - $current;
     $span = ceil($span / (60 * 60 * 24));

     echo 'You have less than '.$span.' days!';

} else {

    echo 'Time has already expired!';

}
```

The above will output

```
You have less than 39 days!
```

Comment: floor should be used in place of ceil

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is set a [DateTime Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for each unix timestamp you have. Compare the two Objects with DateTime's [Diff Function](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

```
$TodaysDate = new DateTime();
$TodaysDate->setTimestamp(time());
$ExperationDate= new DateTime('2014-10-01');
$interval = $TodaysDate->diff($ExperationDate);

If($interval <= 0){
   echo 'Product Expired';
}
```

Their are multiple ways you can set the time in the DateTime Object, using timestamps or keywords or specific date formats.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the current time from your timestamp and divide - Unix time is in seconds.